# react : Problem with \n while sending an email

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome

After a long searching at the internet included in stack overflow, I have been understood my problem but without a way to figure it out.
I have a server in js that sends a mail that client in react send a post request. 
Everything is fine, the email has been send but, all the messege in one long line. 
I have been tried everything to figure it, included '\n', '\n\r', '/\n\r/', ' ',"\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029",
, ,'%0A%0D','%3C%2Fbr%3E','%20%3A%0D%0A' and even more varietion of these but really without success. 
Also I read about the signes '\n \t \r <' and google chrome has delete it while sending url so I try to send it in some different ways but without any success.
It's my first app in react well it should be really easy and looks like redicules, but I really dont find any soloution.

Maybe im missing here something ?

my client send it to the server :

```
      email.totalMessage = "Mail content:"+ "\n" +" First Name: " + email.firstName +
      ""+ "\n" +"Last Name: " + email.lastName + ""+ "\n" +"Mail Address: " + email.emailAddress +
      ""+ "\n" +"Phone Number: "+ email.phoneNumber;
      fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:4000/send-email?recipient=${email.emailAddress}
             &sender=${'JonesFormTesting@test.com'}&topic=${'New Lead from Jones ✔'}
             &text=${email.totalMessage}`) //query string url
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

And the server is just get the total message and send it :

```
APP.get('/send-email', (req,res) => {

    //Get Variables from query string - the details of the email to send
    const { recipient, sender, topic, text } = req.query; 

    //Sendgrid Data Requirements
    const msg = {
        to: recipient, 
        from: sender,
        subject: topic,
        text: text,
    }

    //Send Email
    SG_MAIL.send(msg)
    .then((msg) => console.log('The message has been sent, great job.'));
});
```

My mail output :

```
Mail content: First Name: XXXLast Name: XXXMail Address: XXX@gmail.comPhone Number: XXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Probably sending as html not text which would honor the `\n`. Check docs for email library on how to send text only. Could also try changing `\n` to `<br/>` quickly to test if it is html

Comment: As I said before, the google-chrome disable to use the char '<'.

Comment: The right way to add line breaks in text emails is '\r\n'. I have used this before, and it does work. However, if you want your email to be 'consistently' formatted in all email clients, you might want to give html emails a shot. The '<' chars need not come from client directly, you can replace all '\n' with '<br />'  on server side.

Comment: Do you mean that in the client put '\r\n' and in the server I should use replace function  all '\n' with '<br />' ? Whats the diffrence ? google-chrome said it doesn't accept this '<' char.

Comment: So, I just tried it and it doesn't work. In the client I put "\r\n" and in the server i put this command : msg.text.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");